# Make a Div slide away on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

I want to make my header content (logo) slide away to the left on scroll, leaving the fixed menu left. I have gotten the content to disappear but the slide itself is from top to bottom which makes it just appear as a longer scroll more than a slide away effect.

What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this header or similar: http://lifeinthegrid.com/simple-css-fixed-header/

As you see, once you scroll the header makes a really nice slide away to the left and leaving a fixed menu hanging.

This is the code I have been using so far:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
        $("#header_content").hide(300);
    } else {
       $("#header_content").show(300);
    }
});
</script>
```

The code makes the div disappear but not with a nice slide away to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery ui.

```
$('#header_content').hide("slide", {direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

read the docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$("#header_content").animate(function(){
    right: 9999;
}, 300});
```

To animate the css `right` property to 9999, and again back to 0. You will need to have `position` set to something other than static in your CSS for this to work.

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)